# CORS issue with Confluent kafka rest proxy

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-rest

I am facing some problem in my own Kafka(confluent) setup.

Please find the below issue

**CORS Issue :- Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

I googled and found below settings should be change in this file ***/
home/kafka/confluent-5.0.0/etc/kafka-rest/kafka-rest.properties***.

But by default below code is there. Still CORS is not working. In response the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is not coming

```
access.control.allow.origin=*
access.control.allow.methods=GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS,HEAD
```

Advance thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your system properly answering the _preflight_ request, or does that run into an error or something maybe, perhaps because you did not set up any routing for this particular request method?

Comment: @misorude I am getting status 200 OK with these headers `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 26 Nov 2018 13:35:02 GMT
Content-Type: application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml
Allow: HEAD,POST,GET,OPTIONS
Last-Modified: Mon, 26 Nov 2018 13:35:02 UTC
Content-Length: 1832
Server: Jetty(9.4.11.v20180605)`

Comment: What’s the request method of that? I doubt it is the actual preflight request.

Comment: @misorude It's a GET request

Comment: A Preflight request uses the OPTIONS method.

Comment: could you please let us know what is the property `listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8081` set  in etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties

Comment: @RajkumarNatarajan `listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8081`